# Hidden columns of HTML table are also exporting

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html-table

I have an HTML table for which I have a drop-down, also so that user can see whatever row he wants to see I have an export button. When user clicks on export button I am exporting the data to Excel.

While exporting I am not exporting the hidden row, while applying CSS property `display:none` I am adding a class there to all the hidden rows and removing them while exporting. But still when I export the data extra two columns are exporting, and I don't know why.

```
$("#save").on("click", function() {
        var selectedType = [];
        $.each($(".dropdown-menu input[type='checkbox']:checked"), function() {
            selectedType.push($(this).val());
        });
        $.each($("#salesBreakupTable tr.filterData td:nth-child(2)"), function() {
            if (jQuery.inArray($(this).text(), selectedType) == -1 && $(this).text() != "Total") {
                $(this).parent().css("display", "none");
                $(this).parent().addClass("hide-data"); //class i am adding to hidden rows
            } else {
                $(this).parent().css("display", "");
                $(this).parent().removeClass("hide-data");
            }
        });
    });
    $("#export").click(function() { //export button on click
        var copyTable = $("#salesBreakupTable").clone(false).attr('id', '_copy_dailySales');

        copyTable.insertAfter($("#dailySales"));
        copyTable.find('.hide-data').remove(); //removing rows while exporting

        copyTable.table2excel({
            filename: "Daily Sales Report.xls"
        });
        copyTable.remove();
    });
```

[Link to Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/draj8126/03vag5de/)

When I am selecting `credit` from the drop-down it is exporting like this:

[image: this]

Two columns are extra after the table I have colored the red.

### Note

For some reasons I cannot use Data-tables because data-tables is not exporting col-span, it aligns all the columns to left one by one, then data which looks very bad in Excel.

### Edit

I just found the reason why it is exporting extra columns, the columns which I am fixing with data-tables are those columns, here I have fixed first two columns so they are exporting extra on excel

### Edit

If there is any other approach I am open to that, I have tried Data-tables but it is not exporting columns with col-span, that's why I am using `table2export`.

Comment: It would appear that you are exporting the data within your object, and this without checking the "visibility" of the contents. I would log to console the contents of the object before and after `copyTable.find('.hide-data').remove();` and see if it is removing anything at all.

Comment: yup it is removing,the issue is whenever i am using data-tables fixed columns it is exporting that columns extra, i have tried  on other tables also where there is no `display:hidden` i am exporting full table but it exports that fixed columns extra

Comment: @FDavidov hey can you help me out please

Comment: It seems you may need to remove the fixed columns the same way you are removing the hidden rows while exporting.
 `copyTable.find('td:eq(1),th:eq(1)').remove();
 copyTable.find('td:eq(2),th:eq(2)').remove();`

Comment: @SadhanaDhande hey it didn't work :(

Comment: @SadhanaDhande but if it work thought it is not a good solution because it will remove first two columns `Billdate` and `SalesType` Which is bad, i just want to remove the extra columns which are exporting

Comment: @manishthakur Check my answer. I think, that's the thing what you are looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding this line will do the job for you:

```
copyTable.find('.DTFC_LeftWrapper').remove(); //removing static columns while exporting
```

Here is the fiddle with the updated [code](https://jsfiddle.net/sasiddiqui/pzs72myn/)